# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: REFLECTION While deploying on Tomcat 7.0.78

Tags: java, tomcat

I am creating web service application (REST Producer) and while deploying on server, I am seeing below exception.

```
  SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: REFLECTION
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.<init>(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:473)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1170)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:145)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:236)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:172)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:132)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:334)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:431)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:394)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:298)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlApplicationContextImpl.<init>(WadlApplicationContextImpl.java:72)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlFactory.init(WadlFactory.java:97)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.initWadl(RootResourceUriRules.java:169)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:106)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1298)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:169)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:775)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:766)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:488)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1182)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1072)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5368)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5660)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Jul 13, 2017 11:14:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [jersey-servlet] in web application [/InventoryAPIProducer] threw load() exception
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: REFLECTION
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.<init>(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:473)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1170)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:145)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:236)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:172)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:132)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:334)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:431)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:394)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:298)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlApplicationContextImpl.<init>(WadlApplicationContextImpl.java:72)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlFactory.init(WadlFactory.java:97)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.initWadl(RootResourceUriRules.java:169)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:106)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1298)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:169)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:775)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:766)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:488)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1182)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1072)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5368)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5660)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Below is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mkyong.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>InventoryAPIProducer</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>InventoryAPIProducer</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <swagger-annotations-version>1.5.13</swagger-annotations-version>
        <jodatime-version>2.9.9</jodatime-version>
        <squareup-version>2.7.5</squareup-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <!-- add slf4j interfaces to classpath -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger-annotations-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>${jodatime-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>${squareup-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
            <artifactId>logging-interceptor</artifactId>
            <version>${squareup-version}</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
            <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>InventoryAPIProducer</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I referred similar issue on this forum but none of the solution worked for me. This issue is mostly related to CXF framework (As suggestion in other post) but I am not using it.

I tried adding Server Runtime as Library but not resolved.

Can anyone please help me how to resolve it?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the resolution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

i got same error and I would have had an com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl 2.0.5 then cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws provided a com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl 2.2.11.And there is a conflict between them. After I removed the vesion 2.0.5 ,It works well.

Comment: Thanks. But I am not using any of these jars in my pom.xml